# Cannot locate specified Dockerfile

Tags: docker

**PS E:\wamp64\www\project> docker --version**
Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3

File : **projet/docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:


queue:
    build:
        context: "./docker/queue/"
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    environment:
        - "RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user"
        - "RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=pass"
    ports:
        - "55672:5672"
        - "15672"
    volumes:
        - "queue:/var/lib/rabbitmq:rw"
    networks:
        - "default"

maildev:
    image: djfarrelly/maildev
    ports:
        - "1080:80"
        - "1025:25"
    networks:
        - "default"

build:
    build: ./docker/build/
    volumes:
        - ".:/home/docker:rw"


networks:
    default: {}

volumes:
    db: {}
    queue: {}
```

File : **project/docker/queue/Dockerfile.dev**

```
  FROM rabbitmq:3.6

  RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

When I ran docker-compose up, gives me this

```
   Building queue
   ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
```

Comment: Maybe `dockerfile: ./docker/queue/Dockerfile.dev` ?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce but was not able to. Perhaps you wrote the paths in the OP wrong on purpose? `project/docker/queue/Dockerfile.dev` and `projet/docker-compose.yml`, where the first folder lacks the c leter. It's the only issue I can think of. Also, which are the permissions of such Dockerfile? It should be readable from the docker group.

Comment: when I excute docker-machine ls  : NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS  / So no machines exist